# Replace non-numeric characters in string

Tags: python-3.x, random

I would like to know how to replace non-numeric characters in a single string with different random integers.

I have tried the following:

```
text = '1$1#387'
rec_1 = re.sub("\D+",str(random.randint(0,9)),text)
```

It then produced:

```
output: 1717387
```

As you can see, the non-numeric characters have been replaced by the same integer. I would like each non-numeric character to be replaced by a different integer. For example:

```
desired output: 1714387
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a function as the replacement value:

```
def replacement(match):
    return str(random.randint(0, 9))

text = '1$1#387'
rec_1 = re.sub(r"\D", replacement, text)
```

`rec_1` is now `"1011387"`, or `"1511387"`, ...

Comment: you can also use a lambda like `lambda x: str(random.randint(0, 9))` instead of `replacement`

Comment: Thank you @L3viathan so much!

Answer (score 2):

That's because the randint function is called only 1 time.
You can use a `lambda` to get a new randint each time:

```
rec_1 = re.sub("\D+", lambda x: str(random.randint(0, 9)), text)
```